# "Authenticator" missing in DataGrip Snowflake connector

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datagrip

When I'm setting up a Snowflake data connection in DataGrip, I only have 'User & Password' or 'No auth' under the Authentication dropdown. I'm specifically looking for 'Authenticator', as per Snowflake's instructions: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/snowflake.html

Does anyone know why 'Authenticator' isn't showing up? I have the latest stable driver, and I downloaded DataGrip from its website just this morning, so it should be the latest version.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, I stuck with 'User & Password' and manually added "&authenticator=externalbrowser" to the URL and that worked. Clued in to this by reading https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-use.html#setting-up-browser-based-sso